# Whenever I try to edit /etc/hosts with Vi or Nano /private/etc/hosts is opened instead

Tags: macos, network

For work reasons I kept some sites blocked in `/etc/hosts` but I need now to make them available again.

For this, I tried to open `/etc/hosts` file but to my surprise the editors (Vi or Nano) opened another one located on the path `/private/etc/hosts`.

How could be the original configuration file opened?

Comment: I can not recreate your issue in High Sierra or Monterey. Which version of macOS are you using? Are you booted to Recovery mode?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I use BigSur version 11.4. It was not recovery mode when I had discovered the issue.

Answer (score 11):

As you can see using utilities like [`stat`](https://ss64.com/osx/stat.html), [`file`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html), or [`ls`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html), `/etc` is a [*symbolic link*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to `/private/etc`:

```sh
stat -F /etc
#=> lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 11 May  9 23:30:48 2022 /etc@ -> private/etc

file -h /etc
#=> /etc: symbolic link to private/etc

ls -Fl1 /etc
#=> /etc@
```

Comment: There is also `ls -ld /etc`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. To me as a linux user it was unknown fact.

Answer (score 3):

You can confirm that `/private/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hosts` are two separate file system entries for the same inode with `ls -i`:

```
% ls -i /etc/hosts /private/etc/hosts
1278801 /etc/hosts         1278801 /private/etc/hosts
```

It doesn't really matter *why* the inodes are the same; what matters is that you are editing the same file regardless of which name you use.

Comment: Doesn't work. What if they're on two filesystems?

Comment: Then the OP will know that they need to figure out which file is the correct one to edit. (But then it would also be *extremely* surprising if `<cmd> /etc/hosts` opened the other one instead.)